# How can I remove "for loop iteration" by using torch tensor operator?

Tags: for-loop, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I want to get rid of "for loop iteration" by using Pytorch functions in my code. But the formula is complicated and I can't find a clue. Can the "for loop iteration" in the below replaced with the Torch operation?

```py
B=10
L=20
H=5

mat_A=torch.randn(B,L,L,H)
mat_B=torch.randn(L,B,B,H)
tmp_B=torch.zeros_like(mat_B)

for x in range(L):
    for y in range(B):
        for z in range(B):
            tmp_B[:,y,z,:]+=mat_B[x,y,z,:]*mat_A[z,x,:,:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a good setup for applying [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html). However, we first need to explicit the `:` placeholders by defining each individual accumulation term.

In order to do so, consider the shape of your intermediate tensor results. The first, `mat_B[x,y,z]` is shaped `(H,)`, while the second `mat_A[z,x,]` is shaped `(L, H)`.

In pseudo-code your initial operation is as follows:

```
for x, y, z, l, h in LxBxBxLxH:
    tmp_B[:,y,z,:] += mat_B[x,y,z,:]*mat_A[z,x,:,:]
```

Knowing this, we can reformulate your initial loop in pseudo-code as:

```
for x, y, z, l, h in LxBxBxLxH:
    tmp_B[l,y,z,h] += mat_B[x,y,z,h]*mat_A[z,x,l,h]
```

Therefore, we can apply `torch.einsum` by using the same notation as above:

```
>>> torch.einsum('xyzh,zxlh->lyzh', mat_B, mat_A)
```

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation. It really helps me to understand and apply einsum! Thank you so much!